# ¿Cómo puedo imprimir la matriz?

Tags: java

```
 public void IncluirEmpleado() {

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayEmpleado.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arrayEmpleado[0].length; j++) {
                Empleado obj = new Empleado();
                obj.setnombre = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el nombre del empleado");
                obj.setDepartamento = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el departamento correspondiente");
                obj.setPuesto = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el tipo de puesto");
                obj.setAñosLaborando = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese los años laborando");
                obj.setEmpleadoID(i++);
                obj.setSalario = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el salario"));

                arrayEmpleado[i] = obj;

            }


*************** AQUI VA LA CLASE CON LOS GETTERS Y SETTERS ***********

public class Empleado {

    private String nombre;
    private String departamento;
    private String puesto;
    private int añosLaborando;
    private int empleadoID;
    private double salario;

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getDepartamento() {
        return departamento;
    }

    public void setDepartamento(String departamento) {
        this.departamento = departamento;
    }

    public String getPuesto() {
        return puesto;
    }

    public void setPuesto(String puesto) {
        this.puesto = puesto;
    }

    public int getAñosLaborando() {
        return añosLaborando;
    }

    public void setAñosLaborando(int añosLaborando) {
        this.añosLaborando = añosLaborando;
    }

    public int getEmpleadoID() {
        return empleadoID;
    }

    public void setEmpleadoID(int empleadoID) {
        this.empleadoID = empleadoID;
    }

    public double getSalario() {
        return salario;
    }

    public void setSalario(double salario) {
        this.salario = salario;
    }


}
```

Comment: ¿Es necesario repetir la pregunta tantas veces?. Debes explicar bien el problema que tienes "***no funciona***" no nos dice nada, por favor lee [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). ;)

Comment: La primera parte del for no me esta funcionando para almacenar la informacion en los setter. Repeti muchas veces para que me dejara publicar la pregunta ya que no me dejaba publicarlo.

Comment: Bueno al parecer *arrayEmpleado* no es una matriz según esta en el for, edita tu pregunta y agrega también la parte del código donde declaras *arrayEmpleado*, también adjunta si te muestra algún error. ;)

Comment: Hmm... Podrías hacer un override del método toString de tu clase empleado y luego simplemente usas Arrays.toString(arreglo)

Answer (score 0):

```
public void imprimir(Empleado[][] arrayEmpleados)
 {
    String datosEmpleado = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayEmpleados.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < arrayEmpleados[0].length; j++)
        {
           datosEmpleado += arrayEmpleados[i][j].getNombre() + ", ";
        }
        datosEmpleado += (i == arrayEmpleados.lenght-1) ? "]" : "]\n[";
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, datosEmpleado);
 }
```

te imprimirá algo como:

```
["juan", "rodrigo", "santiago"]
["sara", "pepe", "antonio"]
```